# How to load a large CSV file to Postgresql RDS in AWS using Python3

Tags: postgresql, python-3.6, amazon-rds

I have a 20 GB csv file with 50 columns and 50 million records. I would like to automate this loading of  huge csv file to my RDS postgresql instance using Python3. This csv file is stored in S3 bucket.
Any help on this appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install psycopg2:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Create your table (modify the sql to your needs):

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=dbname user=user")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE sometablename(
some_col integer PRIMARY KEY,
some_col1 text,
some_col2 text,
some_col3 text)""")
conn.commit()
```

Load the data:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()
with open('your_file.csv', 'r') as f:
next(f) # Skip the header row.
cur.copy_from(f, 'sometablename', sep=',')
conn.commit()
```

An alternative way would be through a subprocess:

```
host = "YOUR_HOST"
username = "YOUR_USERNAME"
dbname = "YOUR_DBNAME"

table_name = "my_table"
file_name = "my_10gb_file.csv"
command = "\copy {} FROM '{}' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER".format(table_name, file_name)

psql_template = 'psql -p 5432 --host {} --username {} --dbname {} --command "{}"'

bash_command = psql_template.format(host, username, dbname, command.strip())

process = subprocess.Popen(bash_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 

output, error = process.communicate()
```

Comment: Also this link also useful. 
https://www.mydatahack.com/how-to-bulk-load-data-into-postgresql-with-python/

Comment: Will above methods be faster than using Pandas "to_sql" with "chunksize" and method "multi"?

Answer (score 0):

RDS has a special [extension to PostgreSQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html#USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import) for importing data from S3.  You can use python's psycopg2 to invoke the aws_s3.table_import_from_s3() SQL function, but there is nothing particularly "pythonic" about doing so, any other way of issuing commands to the database would work as well.

If you don't like that for some reason, you can use one [python library](https://pypi.org/project/s3-streaming/) to open a stream from S3, then pass that file-like object to psycopg2's copy_from or copy_expert.